# grep only certain expressions involving quotation marks

Tags: regex, grep

I have a txt file from which I want to get only the expressions of the type
'USA_word*' where * is whatever ( I don't want the whole line, only the expressions )

I try the command

```
grep -oP ''USA_word*''
```

But I get a list :

```
USA_word
USA_word
USA_word
.....
```

without the part signified by the *.

Comment: Maybe `grep -o 'USA_word[^[:blank:]]*'`? That should work if by "expressions" you mean any 0+ non-whitespace chars.

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
grep -o 'USA_word[^[:blank:]]*'
```

The `[^[:blank:]]*` part matches 0+ non-whitespace chars.

Besides, this does not use `-P` PCRE option, and uses a pure BRE POSIX regex making it compatible with the majority of `grep` implementations.